# Executable jar with dependencies and dll dependency using maven

Tags: java, maven, jogl

I have a Java project using 4 OpenGL jars and 1 dll that I've received to work with as a Project for a course in Computer Graphics.
I want to make maven build it for me into an executable jar so I could just git clone my repo from a different computer and build it using maven for execution. (Preferably using `maven clean install`)

What I did so far:

- Installed the 4 jars and the dll into a local repository inside the project.
  This way, I am just setting the dependencies and the files are copied from the git repo, for example:

  ```
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>local-maven-repo</id>
            <url>file:///${project.basedir}/local-maven-repo</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.computer.graphics</groupId>
            <artifactId>jogl</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.computer.graphics</groupId>
            <artifactId>gluegenrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <type>dll</type>
        </dependency>
        ...
  ```
- Set maven assembly plugin with an assembly.xml in src/assembly.xml:

  ```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>

            <configuration>
                <!--        Configure a class for executable jar        -->
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>Main class</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <!--          Points to the assembly descriptor to use          -->
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>

            <!--        Bind goal assembly:single into build process        -->
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                    <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
  ```
- Tried to include the jars and the dll into the executable jar:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.1.0.xsd">

    <id>graphics-assembly</id>
    <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>

    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <unpack>true</unpack>
            <includes>
                <include>*:jar:*</include>
            </includes>
        </dependencySet>
        <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>*:dll*</include>
            </includes>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

From what I understood, the dll file should be in target folder near the executable jar, but even if I do copy manualy the file, when I try to run the jar using `java -jar executable-jar.jar` for example,
I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out of bounds for length 1
        at jogamp.opengl.windows.wgl.awt.WindowsAWTWGLGraphicsConfigurationFactory.chooseGraphicsConfigurationImpl(WindowsAWTWGLGraphicsConfigurationFactory.java:170)
        at javax.media.nativewindow.GraphicsConfigurationFactory.chooseGraphicsConfiguration(GraphicsConfigurationFactory.java:422)
        at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas.chooseGraphicsConfiguration(GLCanvas.java:1516)
        at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas.addNotify(GLCanvas.java:614)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2801)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.addNotify(Window.java:787)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Frame.addNotify(Frame.java:493)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.show(Window.java:1049)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1720)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1667)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1032)
```

- I am using intellij and simply linked the files using File -> Project Structure -> Libraries -> added the folder containing the jars and the dll.
  When I run / build the project using intellij, everything works.

What am I doing wrong? is there a better way to do that?

Comment: Jar is just similar type of archive file like zip, you can open it with any Zip tools such as 7Zip, and check the distributed Jar file construction

Comment: You're using an obsolete version of JOGL. Please switch to JOGL 2. It's a lot easier as you can just use the JARs containing the native libraries to make a single fat JAR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up deleting the dependencySet of the dll from the assembly file and copy the dll dependency with maven-dependency-plugin as follow:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <artifactItems>
            <artifactItem>
                <groupId>com.computer.graphics</groupId>
                <artifactId>gluegenrt</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <type>dll</type>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                <destFileName>gluegen-rt.dll</destFileName>
            </artifactItem>
        </artifactItems>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException occurred because I was using jdk 16 instead of jdk 12 to run the jar.
Hope this helps others.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into the same problem. This seems to be some known bug in jogl / jogamp, but it was not obvious for me at first what to do.

Just add `--illegal-access=permit` to the VM-Options. In my example it worked out of the box with OpenJDK-15, but I had to add that VM-Option when using OpenJDK-16.

I had the same exception when using Jogamp 2.3.2, in Jogamp 2.4.0 the same hotfix helped, but the exception changed to:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" com.jogamp.opengl.GLException: Unable to determine GraphicsConfiguration: WindowsWGLGraphicsConfiguration[DefaultGraphicsScreen[WindowsGraphicsDevice[type .windows, connection decon, unitID 0, handle 0x0, owner false, NullToolkitLock[obj 0x1dc258d9]], idx 0], pfdID 7, ARB-Choosen true,
    requested GLCaps[rgba 8/8/8/0, opaque, accum-rgba 0/0/0/0, dp/st/ms 16/0/0, dbl, mono  , hw, GLProfile[GL4bc/GL4bc.hw], on-scr[.]],
    chosen    GLCaps[wgl vid 7 arb: rgba 8/8/8/0, opaque, accum-rgba 16/16/16/16, dp/st/ms 24/0/0, dbl, mono  , hw, GLProfile[GL4bc/GL4bc.hw], on-scr[.]]]
    at jogamp.opengl.windows.wgl.awt.WindowsAWTWGLGraphicsConfigurationFactory.chooseGraphicsConfigurationImpl(WindowsAWTWGLGraphicsConfigurationFactory.java:182)
    at com.jogamp.nativewindow.GraphicsConfigurationFactory.chooseGraphicsConfiguration(GraphicsConfigurationFactory.java:424)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas.chooseGraphicsConfiguration(GLCanvas.java:1513)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas.addNotify(GLCanvas.java:609)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2801)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4792)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2801)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4792)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2801)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4792)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JRootPane.addNotify(JRootPane.java:729)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2801)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.addNotify(Window.java:787)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Frame.addNotify(Frame.java:493)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.show(Window.java:1049)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1720)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1667)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1032)
    at global.WindowSingleCanvas.createFrame(WindowSingleCanvas.java:122)
    at global.WindowSingleCanvas.setWindowType(WindowSingleCanvas.java:86)
    at global.WindowSingleCanvas.lambda$new$3(WindowSingleCanvas.java:39)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:316)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

See also: http://forum.jogamp.org/JogAmp-Build-v2-4-0-rc-20210111-td4040955i20.html